How to avoid exceptions in your application log when throwing application exception in Resteasy (Exception Mapping used)?
I spent two days trying to fix a problem with server log being flooded with unwanted exceptions so I thought it may be helpful for other people as well. They looked like this and they happened at every single authenticated request from the client application (standard authenticated request is being sent without authentication and the server should respond with 401 and authentication challenge).
13:14:25,312 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-1) WFLYEJB0034: Jakarta Enterprise Beans Invocation failed on component NexusAuthorizationRestService for method public java.util.List org.jboss.downloadmanager.rest.nexus.NexusAuthorizationRestService.getAllRoles(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws org.jboss.downloadmanager.rest.download.InvalidParametersException,org.jboss.downloadmanager.rest.download.UserUnauthorizedException,org.jboss.downloadmanager.rest.download.InvalidUserCredentialsException,org.jboss.downloadmanager.rest.nexus.MissingCredentialsException: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.jboss.downloadmanager.rest.nexus.MissingCredentialsException
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.18.GA-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:268)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.18.GA-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:390)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@7.4.18.GA-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:160)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.6.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

.......... and another 148 line of stack trace


Simplified rest service. The method returns some data (list of roles) but if the client does not authenticate using "Authorization" header in the request, the server should ask the client to authenticate.
@Stateless
public class MyRestService {

    @GET
    @Path("/allRoles")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<String> getAllRoles(@Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws InvalidUserCredentialsException, MissingCredentialsException {

   if(httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization") == null)
      throw new MissingCredentialsException();
   ............ 

}

The application exception definition.
public class MissingCredentialsException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3388868131554531339L;
}

And finally the exception mapper, that handles the request so the client receives a nice response with authentication challenge:
@Provider
public class MissingCredentialsExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<MissingCredentialsException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(MissingCredentialsException exception) {
        return Response.serverError().header("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"nexus\"").status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).entity("Basic authentication is required!").build();
    }
}


The problem is the exception type. The application logic works as you would expect based on the official documentation. But the document does not mention the fact, that RuntimeException is being treated as a general failure and reported to the log.
If you, however use java.lang.Exception instead, RestEasy decides, that it is probably a wanted application error and keeps your server.log nice and clean.
public class MissingCredentialsException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3388868131554531339L;
}

